# create user in migration Up() using Identity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have added a migration to create a user but the code hangs when it hits `userRepo.Create(...)` and within this method at `_userManager.Create(...)`

```
using (UserRepository userRepo = new UserRepository())
{
    User adminUser = new User() { IsActive = true, UserName = 
    "admin@testing.com", CompanyId = 1, Password = 
    "admintesting" };
    adminUser.Role = new Models.Security.Role() { Id = 2 };
    userRepo.Create(adminUser);
}
```

`Create` method is below

```
public IdentityResult Create(Model.User user)
{
   var userEntity = Mapper.Map<Entity.Security.User>(user);
   _dbContext.Set<Entity.Security.User>().Add(userEntity);
   var result = _userManager.Create(userEntity, userEntity.Password);
   DetachAllEntities();
   return result;
}
```

_dbContext is inherited from IdentityDbContext and instantiated accordingly

```
UserManager<Entity.Security.User, int> _userManager = new UserManager<Entity.Security.User, int>(new UserStore<Entity.Security.User, Entity.Security.Role, int, Entity.Security.UserLogin, Entity.Security.UserRole, Entity.Security.UserClaim>(_dbContext));
```

The equivalent async method works elsewhere in the application but I would like the non-async for the migration sake. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There's not enough info to answer this question. What is `_userManager`? What does the `Create` method do? If there's no async calls in this path, there's no obvious reason for it to hang.

Comment: @DavidG I have edited my question to provide the code for _userManager. Even I expected it to work but unfortunately it hangs.

Comment: Try removing the `_dbContext.Set<Entity.Security.User>().Add(userEntity);` line. I don't think it's necessary if you use the UserManager.